# How can I check if a number is a multiple of another number in dart?

Tags: dart

How can I check if a number is a multiple of another number in dart?  A whole multiple that is

Comment: `someInteger % divisor == 0`. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/num/operator_modulo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulo operator can help you on this. If your remainder is 0 then it is a multiple
Example

```
if (144 % 12 == 0){
print('Multiple');
```

}